# pactl `source` module assigns a random port for mic each time

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

- rear mic, rear line-in, and front mic ports don't work by default on boot (but show "plugged in" in `pavucontrol`)
- rear speaker port works by default on boot, but front headphone needs a sink to be created for it to activate

creating a sink for front headphone port works reliably, but mic on the other hand randomly picks one of the aforementioned ports (rear mic, front mic, rear line-in), sometimes it's:

```
pactl load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:2,2
```

and sometimes:

```
pactl load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:1,2
```

why doesn't it work by default and why is it switching physical ports?

specs:

- ubuntu 22.04 lts, pactl 15.99.1
- motherboard: z690-e,
- audio: 00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 7ad0 (rev 11)